# How to join repeated tables from multiple databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, ssms

I'm trying to select into one large table that combines names, emails, and account names from multiple tables in multiple databases on the same server. I have 4 databases that contain the same tables but have different (region specific) data.

**Ex for the first database:**

```
SELECT t1.FirstName,
       t1.LastName,
       t1.Email,
       t1.AccountID,
       t2.AccountName,
       t2.AccountID
INTO NewContactsTable
FROM DataBase1.dbo.Contacts t1
INNER JOIN DataBase1.dbo.Accounts t2 ON t2.AccountID = t1.AccountID
```

So I would like to do the same thing as above (join Contacts and Accounts tables) but with 3 other additional databases (DataBase2, DataBase3, DataBase4) in a single query.

Comment: Can't you just use UNION ALL and write each query separately?

Comment: are you wondering how to query the other DB? If so, that'd be a linked server, then you would join to them just as you have here.

Comment: Another DB on the same server does not need to be a linked server. Just use the same notation as in the question, but with the other DBs: `Database2.dbo.Accounts` etc.

Comment: Correct @ajeh I just assumed it was on a different server since having the same data on the same server in different DB's doesn't make a lot of sense. But then again this question seems redundant in general.

Comment: @RichBenner Yes, that is what I ended up doing. Newbie here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query could look like this:

```
SELECT t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t1.Email, t1.AccountID,
       t2.AccountName, t2.AccountID
INTO NewContactsTable
FROM DataBase1.dbo.Contacts t1 INNER JOIN
     DataBase1.dbo.Accounts t2
     ON t2.AccountID = t1.AccountID
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t1.Email, t1.AccountID,
       t2.AccountName, t2.AccountID
FROM DataBase2.dbo.Contacts t1 INNER JOIN
     DataBase2.dbo.Accounts t2
     ON t2.AccountID = t1.AccountID
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t1.Email, t1.AccountID,
       t2.AccountName, t2.AccountID
FROM DataBase3.dbo.Contacts t1 INNER JOIN
     DataBase3.dbo.Accounts t2
     ON t2.AccountID = t1.AccountID
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t1.Email, t1.AccountID,
       t2.AccountName, t2.AccountID
FROM DataBase4.dbo.Contacts t1 INNER JOIN
     DataBase4.dbo.Accounts t2
     ON t2.AccountID = t1.AccountID;
```

However, I would be inclined to create the table first and then insert the rows from each of the queries separately.

Comment: While not part of the original question....if you had duplicates in 4 source db/tables...by separating the queries, you could do duplicate-avoidance by running "where not exists" on db/tables 2-4.  Aka, gordon's suggestion is a good one.  it will perform better (probably?) and would allow for other data-integrity-checks.

Comment: That would be the same as using `union` and not `union all`

Comment: I used Union in between the select statements because as @ajeh mentioned `UNION` already selects distinct values whereas `UNION ALL` will take in everything.

Comment: @JonathanPorter . . . Your question suggests that the four databases have *different* data, which is why I used `UNION ALL`.  If the values can be the same, then `UNION` is probably the right thing to use.